# Query to show top 10 rows with highest count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with all the cars that have crossed one road during one week. Now I want know what are the 10 most observed cars in that road.

My idea is:

1) Group the cars and count the number of times that they have crossed the road:

```
   select nplate, count('x') from observations group by nplate;
```

I have to do this because I can have the same car observed multiple times in the same week.

2) Order this group by count from highest to lowest.

3) Take the first 10 of those results.

But I don't know how to do the last two steps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `order by count(*) desc`.  The Oracle way to limit the result to 10 rows is to use a subquery followed by `where rownum < N`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  nplate
        ,       count(*) 
        from    observations 
        group by 
                nplate
        order by
                count(*) desc
        ) sub
WHERE   rownum <= 10
```

Your example uses `count('x')`, which counts the number of rows where `'x' is not null`.  That doesn't hurt but it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: But, what it mean 'sub'? or what is its function?

Comment: @DavidsZarzosoMoreno: It's the name of the subquery. You could use it in the outer `select`, like `sub.nplate`. Naming subqueries is required, you'll get an error if you omit the name.

Comment: @Andomar, *Naming subqueries is required, you'll get an error if you omit the name* - in some cases, but not in this example.

Answer (score 1):

This works for Oracle 12c and above:

```
SELECT nplate,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   observations
GROUP  BY nplate
ORDER  BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has given the answer using a window (analytic) function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT nplate, observation_cnt FROM (
   SELECT nplate, COUNT(*) AS observation_cnt
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
     FROM observations
    GROUP BY nplate
) WHERE rn <= 10
 ORDER BY rn;
```

If there are two (or more) values of `nplate` with the same number of observations, and all have the 10th most observations, and it's important that you get all, then you'll want to use the window function `RANK()` instead:

```
SELECT nplate, observation_cnt FROM (
   SELECT nplate, COUNT(*) AS observation_cnt
        , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
     FROM observations
    GROUP BY nplate
) WHERE rn <= 10
 ORDER BY rn;
```

(It's possible you'll want `DENSE_RANK()` as well!)

In short, window functions give you a flexibility that the `ROWNUM` and `FETCH FIRST` solutions do not.